# Find the most similar number from list of lists in a dictionary python

Tags: python, list

I have a dictionary where the values are a list of lists:

```
dict1 = {"['x1', 'y1']": [['r1', 'r2'], [78, 125]],
    "['x1', 'y1']": [['r1', 'r2'], [77, 112]],
    "['x1', 'y1']": [['r1', 'r2'], [73, 110]],
    "['x2', 'y2']": [['r2', 'r3'], [71, 103]]}
```

I am also giving a list of lists as input **which i want to find in dict1**

```
 input1 = [['r1', 'r2'], [72, 112]]
```

The first list `['r1', 'r2']` is the same as in `dict1` and can still be easily found. But for the second list, i need to find approximate numbers in `dict1`. So for `[72, 112]` it's `[73, 110]`.I don't understand how to do it

Estimated output I want:

```
output = { "['x1', 'y1']": [['r1', 'r2'], [73, 110]]}
```

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: don't just ask the same question without any changes [old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75284012/find-the-most-similar-list-of-lists-from-a-dictionary-python). Add details, make an effort ([mcve]), etc

Comment: I don't really understand why my question was closed. I changed the title to be more clear.

Comment: @Rory It was probably closed because there's no indication that you've tried to help yourself. Maybe you just forgot to add your code to the question. Also, are you aware that you cannot have duplicate keys in a Python dictionary? Your dictionary will only have two key/value pairs - probably not what you were expecting. You will also need to clarify what you mean by "similar" in mathematical terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brief about the code.

```
(1) mini variable is set to the positive infinity to initialize the minimum difference to a high value.
(2) looping through all key-value pairs in the dict1
(3) if value[0] == input1[0]: if this condition satisfy it will check the `abs` value b/w input and dictionary if it is lower than mini it will update the mini value and also output value is updated
```

**Code:**

```
dict1 = {"['x1', 'y1']": [['r1', 'r2'], [78, 125]],
    "['x1', 'y1']": [['r1', 'r2'], [77, 112]],
    "['x1', 'y1']": [['r1', 'r2'], [73, 110]],
    "['x2', 'y2']": [['r2', 'r3'], [71, 103]]}
input1 = [['r1', 'r2'], [72, 112]]
mini=float('inf')
output = {}
for key, value in dict1.items():
    if value[0] == input1[0]:
        diff1 = abs(value[1][0] - input1[1][0])
        diff2 = abs(value[1][1] - input1[1][1])
        if diff1+diff2 < mini:
            output[key] = value
            mini=diff1+diff2
print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
{"['x1', 'y1']": [['r1', 'r2'], [73, 110]]}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why are you summing diff1 and diff2?

Comment: just to get difference b/w them.. at last you want the value which is closest to input value.. @Rory

Comment: I understand you are finding the closest difference between value and input, but then you do  if diff1+diff2 < mini. Why?

Comment: basically `if diff1+diff2 < mini.` helping us to find minimum absolute difference let's say first time the `abs` is 9 the key and value is updated but then suppose another value comes which have `abs` less than 9 than it will update the `value` as well as `mini` also so basically it helping to find out total minimum absolute value.. @Rory